# Nexus3 Unable to update instance pid: No locks available "nexus"

Tags: docker, nas, nexus3

I have a nexus3 instance running inside a docker container with the /nexus-data directory mounted as a volume on some network attached storage.  The docker container died unexpectidly and now wont come up as it throws the error

```
Unable to update instance pid: No locks available "nexus"
```

How do I get this to start up again

Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.6.0-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was nothing to do with nexus itself.  The NFS mounts got messed up and nexus was unable to aquire a lock